# Hide/Show element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show/hide an input on an event. This works:

```
      <input type="text" class="search"placeholder="Search">

      $('.search').hide()
```

The problem is it doesn't work the other way around. I need to hide it at first so I use type="hidden" and then .show() but that doesn't work, why?

Comment: You can't have done any research on this problem yourself, or the documentation would have lead you to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.hide` and `.show` don't have anything to do with the `type` attribute. An `input type=text` does not become an `input type=hidden` when you invoke jQuery's `.hide` on it.

If you want your element to start hidden, use the CSS property `display: none`, or simply invoke `.hide` on it when the DOM has loaded.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> [`hide`] is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`, except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery - there's a useful function called `toggle()`. You'd do something like:

```
 $('.search').toggle()
```

This hides a visible element and shows a hidden one.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/